# Count items for each order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been stuck for a week with this SQL query.

I have the following table:

```
CLIENT  | DELIV. C. |
---------------------
10      | 200       |
10      | 700       |
10      | 700       |
40      | 200       |
30      | 300       |
20      | 400       |
30      | 400       |
50      | 900       |
```

I need to produce the following result

```
CLIENTS W/1 DELIV C|CLIENTS W/ 2 DELIV C|CLIENTS W/ 3 DELIV C| CLIENTS 4+ DELIV C|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            3      |             1      |          1         |        0          |
```

Comment: What does your current query look like / what have you tried?

Comment: Are you working with SQL or MySQL?

Comment: can you explain how you got those results `  3      |             1      |          1         |        0 ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an aggregation on an aggregation (the second is to do the pivoting):

```
select sum(NumDeliveries = 1) as "CLIENTS W/1 DELIV C",
       sum(NumDeliveries = 2) as "CLIENTS W/2 DELIV C",
       sum(NumDeliveries = 3) as "CLIENTS W/3 DELIV C",
       sum(NumDeliveries > 3) as "CLIENTS 4+ DELIV C"
from (select client, count(*) as NumDeliveries
      from t
      group by client
     ) t;
```

In most other databases, you would write out the conditions using `case` as:

```
select sum(case when NumDeliveries = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as "CLIENTS W/1 DELIV C",
```

MySQL also supports this standard notation.

EDIT:

The subquery is counting the number of deliveries for each client.  This is pretty basic SQL and it is what you want to pivot (that is, move from rows to columns).

The outer query is pivoting the data by using conditional aggregation.  The expression:

```
       sum(NumDeliveries = 2) as "CLIENTS W/2 DELIV C",
```

is evaluated as follows:

The expression `NumDeliveries = 2` returns 1 when the condition is true and false otherwise.  The sum is then the sum of the number of times when this is true.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that worked like a charm. Would you be so kind to explain me the logic behind this query. I am a beginner at SQL and I would like to understand SQL better. Thank you again